# Using Oracle types in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, plsql

In this moment, I'm use a Oracle database in my project. I have one type object and need to map it to Java.

```
//PL/SQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XPTO.TABLE_XPTO FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
```

It is possible to map this type to a class? For example:

```
//JAVA
TABLE_XPTO xpto = new TABLE_XPTO;
```

Anyone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/)?

Comment: I use JPA and I need to call a procedure. This procedure have one in parameter STRUCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using ArrayDescriptor:

```
//Need to create connection
ArrayDescriptor desArray = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("XPTO.TABLE_XPTO", conn);

//I don't need to send information for procedure
ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(desArray, conn, null);

...
//When you contruct the statement it is needed use the setArray
proc_strm.setArray(7, array_to_pass);
```

For more information go: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/oraarr.htm

It is possible using ARRAY in class? Anyone have a tutorial for this ?